# How Do You Add Your Own Images To The PhotoScroller Example?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, photo

Ive been trying to make my own photoscroller, so users can look at all their different products and switch to another photo by swiping but I'm having a hard time adding my own photos,

this example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html
[example]

does it have to be tiled? if so is there any way i can remove it? or make tile images?

I'm fairly new to objective C and iOS programming

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a tool to generate tiles and found out Photoshop (CS3 or later) includes an option to create JPEG tiles for a tool called Zoomify. From the menu choose File > Export > Zoomify... and in 'Browser Options' fill in the tileSize of 256 x 256 pixels.

After clicking [OK] a folder TileGroup0 will be created with the 256 pixel tiles.
The files are named: `zoomlevel-column-row.jpg`, whereas Photoscroller's example files are named `filename_scale_column_row.png` (the `0-0-0.jpg` file can be discarded). So rename the jpg-files accordingly (`1- = 125_, 2- = 250_, 3- = 500_`, etc.) or just fix `tileName` in `tileForScale:row:col:` (TilingView.m) to load the correct jpg file.